# Create a list of values for each key in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file the looks something like this which I have loaded into a dataframe,

```
keycode, warehouse_id
      1,          WH1
      1,          WH2
      1,          WH1
```

I want to map that to an output that looks like

```
keycode, warehouse_ids
      1,    [WH1, WH2]
```

I am not sure where to start with this in pandas? I tried using a pivot table but the aggregate but can't choose the right agregrate function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)+[`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('keycode,')['warehouse_id'].unique().reset_index()

print(df1)
  keycode, warehouse_id
0       1,   [WH1, WH2]
```

---

**Explanation :**

Generally while using `groupby` with a single operation column like below produces [`Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Series.html) with index as `groupby key`, for that we use [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) to change `index` to `column`:

```
print(df.groupby('keycode,')['warehouse_id'].unique())
keycode,
1,    [WH1, WH2]
Name: warehouse_id, dtype: object

print(type(df.groupby('keycode,')['warehouse_id'].unique()))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> 

print(df.groupby('keycode,')['warehouse_id'].unique().reset_index())
  keycode, warehouse_id
0       1,   [WH1, WH2]
```

Comment: Nice answer (-:

Comment: Forgive my ignorance what is the reset_index doing for me here?

Comment: @tmcnicol Check the explanation.

Comment: @sandeep-kadapa Thanks so much, I would upvote again if I could.

Comment: @tmcnicol Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

pandas **'groupby'** operator is used for doing these type of things.

you can just do:

```
df.groupby('keycode')['warehouse_id'].apply(list)
```

assuming 'df' is your dataframe name.

Answer (score 1):

#### `list(set(iterable))`

```
df.groupby('keycode').warehouse_id.apply(lambda x: [*{*x}]).reset_index()

   keycode warehouse_id
0        1   [WH2, WH1]
```

---

#### `drop_duplicates`

```
df.drop_duplicates().groupby('keycode').warehouse_id.apply(list).reset_index()

   keycode warehouse_id
0        1   [WH1, WH2]
```