# Excel to Python Dictionary format

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

Data is in excel:

| servername | instance |
| --- | --- |
| server1 | a |
| server1 | b |
| server3 | c |

I need to convert into below format:

```json
{
  "server1":["a",b"],
  "server2":["c"]
}
```

I tried using `excel2json` but did not get expected results.

```py
import excel2json
file='C:\\Users\\AAA\\Downloads\\records.xlsx'
excel2json.convert_from_file(file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

1. Read Excel File
2. Create a list of values for each server name using `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` (see also this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53274085/42659) for explanation)
3. Convert to JSON

```py
import pandas as pd  # pip install pandas

# read excel file
df = pd.read_excel(r"77319587.xlsx")

# create a list of values for each server name
df = df.groupby(["servername"])["instance"].unique()

# convert to JSON
json_string = ds.to_json()

print(json_string)
```

---

Or, you could use [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable) and [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) (and [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)):

```py
import json

from collections import defaultdict

from openpyxl import load_workbook  # pip install openpyxl 

data = defaultdict(list)

wb = load_workbook(r"77319587.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

rows = ws.rows
header = next(rows)  # skip header line

for row in rows:
    data[row[0].value].append(row[1].value)

json_string = json.dumps(data)

print(json_string)
```

---

And, if you are able to get your data as a CSV file, then simply use the package [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to read the file. No third party library needed in this case:

```py
import csv
import json

from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

with open(r"77319587.csv", "r", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
    
    reader = csv.reader(file)

    next(reader)  # skip header line
    
    for row in reader:
        data[row[0]].append(row[1])

json_string = json.dumps(data)

print(json_string)
```